# ios check for displayed local notifications

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

assume I scheduled 3 local notifications and when users opens app, three notifications have following states:

```
a) not displayed yet
b) displayed
c) displayed and user taps on this notification and come back to app.
```

How do i detect each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 10 has introduced the `UIUserNotificationCenter`, and deprecated the scheduling and delivery of local notifications via `UIApplication`, so there are some differences depending on which method you are using.  The deprecated methods still work on iOS 10, so if you are targeting iOS earlier than iOS10 then you can continue to use these methods, but you will get deprecation warnings.

For case **a**, a notification that hasn't yet been delivered, details of this notification are available by calling `getPendingNotificationRequests` on an instance of `UIUserNotificationCenter` (iOS 10) or by accessing the `scheduledLocalNotifications` property on your app's `UIApplication` instance (Prior to iOS 10)

For case **b**, a notification that has been delivered but that the user didn't interact with, no information is available.

For case **c**, the notification that the user tapped to launch the app, it depends on the state of the application and how the user interacts with the notification.

- If the app is not running in the foreground or suspended, then the application is launched and the notification payload is delivered to the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` via the `localNotification` key in the options dictionary
- If the app is suspended, then the notification is delivered to `didReceiveLocalNotification` delegate method is called.
- If the notification has custom actions and the user taps one of those then the `application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:` app delegate method is called

Comment: it is `UNUserNotificationCenter`